# Using Python to upload large csv files to Postgres RDS in AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

What's the easiest way to load a large csv file into a Postgres RDS database in AWS using Python?

To transfer data to a local postgres instance, I have previously used a `psycopg2` connection to run SQL statements like:

```
COPY my_table FROM 'my_10gb_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

However, when executing this against a remote AWS RDS database, this generates an error because the `.csv` file is on my local machine rather than the database server:

```
ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
SQL state: 42501
Hint: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206313/copying-csv-to-amazon-rds-hosted-postgresql-database) explains why this doesn't work.

I'm now looking for the Python syntax to automate this using `psql`.  I have a large number of `.csv` files I need to upload, so I need a script to automate this.

Comment: `psql -c "\COPY my_table FROM 'my_10gb_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"` would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the table definitions in the RDS Postgres as normal using `CREATE TABLE` SQL statements.

Then you need to run a `psql` statement like this:

```
psql -p 5432 --host YOUR_HOST --username YOUR_USERNAME --dbname YOUR_DBNAME --command "\copy my_table FROM 'my_10gb_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
```

In Python, we can set this up and execute it as follows:

```
host = "YOUR_HOST"
username = "YOUR_USERNAME"
dbname = "YOUR_DBNAME"

table_name = "my_table"
file_name = "my_10gb_file.csv"
command = "\copy {} FROM '{}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER".format(table_name, file_name)

psql_template = 'psql -p 5432 --host {} --username {} --dbname {} --command "{}"'

bash_command = psql_template.format(host, username, dbname, command.strip())

process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 

output, error = process.communicate()
```